# Cannot locate Derby database within jar file

Tags: java, intellij-idea, derby

I am trying to create a jar file that includes an embedded Derby database. I'm able to successfully embed the database in my project (located on the same level as the src folder), and when I build my project the database files are included in the target folder in IntelliJ. However, once the jar is generated I cannot access the database from within the jar, in a separate project.

The error I keep getting:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Database 'jar:(C:/summer2021/employee-database.jar)employees' not found.
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(SQLExceptionFactory.java:115)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(SQLExceptionFactory.java:141)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Util.java:225)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Util.java:220)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.newSQLException(EmbedConnection.java:3215)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.handleDBNotFound(EmbedConnection.java:772)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.<init>(EmbedConnection.java:442)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.jdbc.InternalDriver$1.run(InternalDriver.java:660)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.jdbc.InternalDriver$1.run(InternalDriver.java:656)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:569)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.jdbc.InternalDriver.getNewEmbedConnection(InternalDriver.java:654)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(InternalDriver.java:300)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(InternalDriver.java:967)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.jdbc.AutoloadedDriver.connect(AutoloadedDriver.java:136)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:681)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:252)
    at com.github.kyleryvn.taxservice.database.Database.queryDatabase(Database.java:11)
    at com.github.kyleryvn.taxservice.Main.main(Main.java:8)
Caused by: ERROR XJ004: Database 'jar:(C:/summer2021/employee-database.jar)employees' not found.
    at org.apache.derby.shared.common.error.StandardException.newException(StandardException.java:300)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(SQLExceptionFactory.java:170)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(SQLExceptionFactory.java:75)
    ... 17 more
```

I know the database is inside the jar somewhere because even when I run the command `jar tf` I can see the database listed.

Code trying to access database:

```
public static void queryDatabase(String query) {
        try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:jar:(C:/summer2021/employee-database.jar)employees")) {
            RowSetFactory factory = RowSetProvider.newFactory();
            CachedRowSet cachedRowSet = factory.createCachedRowSet();

            cachedRowSet.setCommand(query);
            cachedRowSet.execute(connection);

            while (cachedRowSet.next()) {
                System.out.print(cachedRowSet.getString("id") + " ");
                System.out.print(cachedRowSet.getFloat("salary") + " ");
                System.out.println(cachedRowSet.getString("filingStatus"));
            }

        } catch (SQLException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I have tried accessing the jar with a '/' preceding the database name and without it. Both attempts result in the same error, what am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

When trying to load the jar without the '/' in front of the database name I receie this error:

```
C:\Development\jdk-17\bin\java.exe -javaagent:C:\Users\kyles\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\IDEA-U\ch-0\212.5457.46\lib\idea_rt.jar=58403:C:\Users\kyles\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\IDEA-U\ch-0\212.5457.46\bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Users\kyles\Documents\Projects\Java\employee-tax-service\target\classes;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf\2.5.6\spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf-2.5.6.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\2.5.6\spring-boot-starter-2.5.6.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\2.5.6\spring-boot-2.5.6.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\2.5.6\spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.6.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\2.5.6\spring-boot-starter-logging-2.5.6.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.2.6\logback-classic-1.2.6.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.2.6\logback-core-1.2.6.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-to-slf4j\2.14.1\log4j-to-slf4j-2.14.1.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.14.1\log4j-api-2.14.1.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.32\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.32.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\jakarta\annotation\jakarta.annotation-api\1.3.5\jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.5.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.28\snakeyaml-1.28.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\org\thymeleaf\thymeleaf-spring5\3.0.12.RELEASE\thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\org\thymeleaf\thymeleaf\3.0.12.RELEASE\thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\org\attoparser\attoparser\2.0.5.RELEASE\attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\org\unbescape\unbescape\1.1.6.RELEASE\unbescape-1.1.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.32\slf4j-api-1.7.32.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\org\thymeleaf\extras\thymeleaf-extras-java8time\3.0.4.RELEASE\thymeleaf-extras-java8time-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-web\2.5.6\spring-boot-starter-web-2.5.6.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-json\2.5.6\spring-boot-starter-json-2.5.6.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.12.5\jackson-databind-2.12.5.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.12.5\jackson-annotations-2.12.5.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.12.5\jackson-core-2.12.5.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jdk8\2.12.5\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.12.5.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.12.5\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.12.5.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-parameter-names\2.12.5\jackson-module-parameter-names-2.12.5.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-tomcat\2.5.6\spring-boot-starter-tomcat-2.5.6.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-core\9.0.54\tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-el\9.0.54\tomcat-embed-el-9.0.54.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-websocket\9.0.54\tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.54.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\5.3.12\spring-web-5.3.12.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\5.3.12\spring-beans-5.3.12.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\5.3.12\spring-webmvc-5.3.12.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\5.3.12\spring-aop-5.3.12.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\5.3.12\spring-context-5.3.12.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\5.3.12\spring-expression-5.3.12.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\5.3.12\spring-core-5.3.12.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jcl\5.3.12\spring-jcl-5.3.12.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\org\apache\derby\derby\10.15.2.0\derby-10.15.2.0.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\org\apache\derby\derbyshared\10.15.2.0\derbyshared-10.15.2.0.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\org\apache\derby\derbytools\10.15.2.0\derbytools-10.15.2.0.jar;C:\Users\kyles\.m2\repository\com\google\code\gson\gson\2.8.8\gson-2.8.8.jar;C:\Users\kyles\Documents\Projects\Java\embedded-database\target\employee-database.jar com.github.kyleryvn.taxservice.Main
java.sql.SQLException: Failed to start database 'jar:(C:/summer2021/employee-database.jar)employees' with class loader jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@1d44bcfa, see the next exception for details.
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(SQLExceptionFactory.java:115)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(SQLExceptionFactory.java:141)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.seeNextException(Util.java:252)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.bootDatabase(EmbedConnection.java:2855)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.<init>(EmbedConnection.java:411)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.jdbc.InternalDriver$1.run(InternalDriver.java:660)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.jdbc.InternalDriver$1.run(InternalDriver.java:656)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:569)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.jdbc.InternalDriver.getNewEmbedConnection(InternalDriver.java:654)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(InternalDriver.java:300)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(InternalDriver.java:967)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.jdbc.AutoloadedDriver.connect(AutoloadedDriver.java:136)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:681)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:252)
    at com.github.kyleryvn.taxservice.database.Database.queryDatabase(Database.java:11)
    at com.github.kyleryvn.taxservice.Main.main(Main.java:8)
Caused by: ERROR XJ040: Failed to start database 'jar:(C:/summer2021/employee-database.jar)employees' with class loader jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@1d44bcfa, see the next exception for details.
    at org.apache.derby.shared.common.error.StandardException.newException(StandardException.java:300)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(SQLExceptionFactory.java:170)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(SQLExceptionFactory.java:75)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: ERROR XSDB2: Unknown container format at container null : 0
    at org.apache.derby.shared.common.error.StandardException.newException(StandardException.java:300)
    at org.apache.derby.shared.common.error.StandardException.newException(StandardException.java:295)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.FileContainer.readHeaderFromArray(FileContainer.java:796)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.FileContainer.readHeader(FileContainer.java:727)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.InputStreamContainer.openContainer(InputStreamContainer.java:92)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.FileContainer.setIdent(FileContainer.java:379)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.FileContainer.setIdentity(FileContainer.java:361)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.cache.ConcurrentCache.find(ConcurrentCache.java:318)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.BaseDataFileFactory.openContainer(BaseDataFileFactory.java:690)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.BaseDataFileFactory.openContainer(BaseDataFileFactory.java:620)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.xact.Xact.openContainer(Xact.java:1355)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.heap.HeapConglomerateFactory.readConglomerate(HeapConglomerateFactory.java:256)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.CacheableConglomerate.setIdentity(CacheableConglomerate.java:108)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.cache.ConcurrentCache.find(ConcurrentCache.java:318)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.RAMAccessManager.conglomCacheFind(RAMAccessManager.java:474)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.RAMTransaction.findConglomerate(RAMTransaction.java:401)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.RAMTransaction.findExistingConglomerate(RAMTransaction.java:380)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.RAMTransaction.openScan(RAMTransaction.java:1558)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.PropertyConglomerate.openScan(PropertyConglomerate.java:233)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.PropertyConglomerate.readDbProperties(PropertyConglomerate.java:720)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.PropertyConglomerate.getCachedDbProperties(PropertyConglomerate.java:755)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.PropertyConglomerate.getCachedProperty(PropertyConglomerate.java:564)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.PropertyConglomerate.getProperty(PropertyConglomerate.java:632)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.PC_XenaVersion.upgradeIfNeeded(PC_XenaVersion.java:61)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.PropertyConglomerate.<init>(PropertyConglomerate.java:168)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.RAMAccessManager.boot(RAMAccessManager.java:1175)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(BaseMonitor.java:2002)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(TopService.java:334)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startModule(BaseMonitor.java:538)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.FileMonitor.startModule(FileMonitor.java:48)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.bootServiceModule(Monitor.java:460)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.db.BasicDatabase$5.run(BasicDatabase.java:1001)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:569)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.db.BasicDatabase.bootServiceModule(BasicDatabase.java:995)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.db.BasicDatabase.bootStore(BasicDatabase.java:777)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.db.BasicDatabase.boot(BasicDatabase.java:186)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(BaseMonitor.java:2002)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(TopService.java:334)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.bootService(BaseMonitor.java:1830)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startProviderService(BaseMonitor.java:1696)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.findProviderAndStartService(BaseMonitor.java:1529)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startPersistentService(BaseMonitor.java:999)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.startPersistentService(Monitor.java:598)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection$4.run(EmbedConnection.java:4042)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection$4.run(EmbedConnection.java:4038)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:569)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.startPersistentService(EmbedConnection.java:4036)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.bootDatabase(EmbedConnection.java:2816)
    ... 12 more
```

Comment: Assuming you have the correct path to the JAR file location (`C:/summer2021/employee-database.jar`), what is the location of the Derby DB within the JAR itself? You mention it is "located on the same level as the src folder" - but where is that in your JAR? Can you show the JAR file's structure?

Comment: @andrewJames here is a screenshot of what my target folder looks like in IntelliJ: <https://www.dropbox.com/s/zbixlzguq04s8tq/target.png?dl=0>

And when I run the command ```jar tf``` on my generated jar, this is what prints in the command prompt: <https://www.dropbox.com/s/zt3w5nc476fggyq/cmd.png?dl=0>

Comment: Sorry I can't see those screenshots. Your code works for me, by the way, assuming the DB is a top level folder inside the JAR. But just to ask the obvious question: You are running your program at the command line, right using `java -jar`? Not in IntelliJ...

Comment: In a separate project, I'm trying to query the database inside the jar, which I know can be done becuase Apache has documentation on that on their site <http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.11/devguide/cdevdeploy11201.html#cdevdeploy11201> (however it's a little vahue) so yes I'm using intelliJ for that. Those errors appear in the run tab when I run the project from IntelliJ

Comment: I think I am not understanding. Are you trying to access a Derby DB located inside a different JAR from the JAR containing your app? I thought everything was inside just one JAR.

Comment: Correct, I'm trying to access the Derby DB located inside a different JAR. The current project I'm in is attempting to query that database

Comment: OK thanks for correcting me. In that case, your syntax is correct, assuming the DB directory is the top level directory in the other JAR. I have a simple test case which works. There must be some other difference I am not seeing.

Comment: Can you post your test case?

Comment: It is simply this: `Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:jar:(C:/tmp/another_jar.jar)mytestdb");` followed by a JDBC select to show that data can be retrieved. But I see you are now getting an "unknown container format" error - which is a different problem. So maybe the DB was created with a different version of Derby from the one being used by the JDBC driver... I don't know, sorry.